# not able to navigate using different @test annotation

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am having difficulty with selenium webdriver.
This works :

```
@Test
public void testFindElements()throws Exception{
userName = driver.findElement
(By.id("j_userparam"));
userName.sendKeys("abc");               
password = driver.findElement(By.id("j_userpwd"));
password.sendKeys("abc");
submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button"));
submit.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iframeMain']"));
     driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='oim']"));
    element.click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
```

But if I write the lower part in different test annotation , it doesnt work:

```
     @Test
public void Search() throws Exception{

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
    WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iframeMain']"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='oim']"));
    element.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000); 

}
```

I get an error "unable to locate xpath.

Comment: Are there any `@Beforemethod` and `@AfterMethod` annotations used ?

Comment: No, I have used BeforeClass and AfterClass annotation to load the URl and close the driver.

Comment: How are you running this program? using xml file or `Run as TestNG` in Eclipse ?

Comment: RUN AS TESTnG IN ECLIPSE.

Comment: At which line do you get this error `unable to locate xpath` ?

Comment: WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iframeMain']"));